# Unexpected CoordinatorLayout behavior

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

### This is the xml I'm using to create a collapsable toolbar animation:

**The main layout:**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The toolbar layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/AppTheme.toolbarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

**The layout that replaces the `container` FrameLayout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

### The result I get:

[image]

Now the obvious problem is, that the Recyclerview is drawn below the toolbar, and the list starts scrolling only after the toolbar is completely hidden. The intended animation was to scroll the recyclerview at the same time as the toolbar is hidden. From what I've read it may be because the CoordinatorLayout is the subclass of FrameLayout. How do I fix it?

Comment: Include of the Toolbar doesn't work with AppBarLayout: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175526

Comment: if you look at the gif you'll notice it does indeed work.

Comment: Why is there a `FrameLayout` container rather than just the `@+id/recycler_list`? Anyways, I recommend this guide, maybe you'll find a fix to your problem: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: I'm using fragment transitions to replace contents, one of the available contents is the recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `FrameLayout` (`@+id/container`):

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`